# Changing PHP include based on browser detection

Tags: php, ios, include, browser-detection

My website loads and looks exactly the same on regular browsers (IE / Chrome / Firefox) and IOS devices (iphone / ipad / ipod touch). However, for the mobile devices, there's a specific link on the menu that must be different. It loads an off-site page that I have no control on, but one version is for regular browsers, and the other is for mobiles.

Everything on my site is added by PHP includes, including one specifically for the menu links.

I already know how to redirect to another mobile-specific page based on browser detection, but I'm wondering if there is a way to change just this include, depending on which browser is accessing the site.

The intention on doing this is to not have the entire site mirrored just for a different include directly on the code.

Comment: take a look at `get_browser()`

Comment: that will give you all sorts of specific output to drive your branching on for your include selection for the problem element

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, instead of including a different PHP for the whole menu, just to change the specific link on the menu, to point to an intermediate PHP page, and apply the redirection on this page? This way you can include the same PHP for your menu whatever the client browser, and when the user click on the link in your menu, it requests the intermediate page that will do your trick to redirect to the standard or mobile-specific version of your off-site page based on browser detection (And you said you know how to do this redirect stuff so you're ok for that part)

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Did not need it after all. The client got a different off-site page that did the detection by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own solution, you need to ensure that your `browscap.ini` is up-to-date. You can download the latest one from the [Browser Capabilities Project](https://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads). Then, update your `php.ini` using this as a guide:

```
[browscap]
browscap = /path/to/your/php_browscap.ini
```

Finally, you can call [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) in PHP to get the `ismobiledevice` value.

There are PHP projects that do the work for you:

- [php-mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) is easy to use and looks like it gets regular updates.
- [phpbrowscap](https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap) uses browscap, but it works if you're running in a shared hosting environment without access to your `php.ini` to modify the `browscap` directive.